Proof of $L(f,P) \leq L(f,Q)$. For $P,Q$ partitions of $[a,b]$
i'm having difficulty with the prove of the follow lemma:
"For two partions $P$, and $Q$, where $P \subseteq Q$, we have $L(f,P) \leq L(f,Q)$ and $U(f,P) \geq U(f,Q)$"
The argument for this lemma is not the problem. I'm struggling with the proof, is hard for me develop the proof. Especially with the notation for this sums. Can you guys give me a feedback? this is correct?
Proof:
Consider that $P=\{T_{0},T_{1},...,T_{k}\}$ and $Q=\{t_{0},t_{1},...,t_{n}\}$, where $T_{i} \in Q$, for all $i \in [0,k]$.
Denote $T_{i}=t_{\alpha_{i}}$ such that $0\leq \alpha_{i} \leq n$. So $T_{0}=t_{0}$, and $T_{k}=t_{n}$. Follow that:
\begin{align}
T_{i}-T_{i-1} &= t_{\alpha_{i}}-t_{\alpha_{i-1}} \\
&= t_{\alpha_{i}}-t_{\alpha_{i-1}} + \sum_{\alpha_{i-1}<j<\alpha_{i}}(t_{j}-t_{j}) \\
&= \sum_{j=\alpha_{i-1}+1}^{\alpha_{i}}(t_{j})-\sum_{j=\alpha_{i-1}}^{\alpha_{i}-1}(t_{j}) \\
&= \sum_{j=\alpha_{i-1}+1}^{\alpha_{i}}(t_{j})-\sum_{j=\alpha_{i-1}+1}^{\alpha_{i}}(t_{j-1}) = \sum^{\alpha_{i}}_{j=\alpha_{i-1}+1}(t_{j}-t_{j-1})
\end{align}
For $i \in [1,k]$. Consider $m_{i} = min(f([T_{i-1},T_{i}]))$; for $i \in [1,k]$, and $m'_{j} = min(f([t_{j-1},t_{j}]))$; for $j \in [1, n]$. Since $[t_{j-1},t_{j}] \subseteq [T_{i-1},T_{i}]$, we have $m_{i} \leq m'_{j}$, for all $j \in [\alpha_{i-1}+1, \alpha_{i}]$. Then:
$$\sum_{j=\alpha_{i-1}+1}^{\alpha_{i}}m_{i}(t_{j}-t_{j-1}) \leq \sum_{j=\alpha_{i-1}+1}^{\alpha_{i}}m'_{j}(t_{j}-t_{j-1})$$
From which it takes us to:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{k}\left(\sum_{j=\alpha_{i-1}+1}^{\alpha_{i}}(m_{i}(t_{j}-t_{j-1}))\right) \leq \sum_{i=1}^{k}\left(\sum_{j=\alpha_{i-1}+1}^{\alpha_{i}}(m'_{j}(t_{j}-t_{j-1}))\right)$$

First: $\sum_{j=\alpha_{i-1}+1}^{\alpha_{i}}(m_{i}(t_{j}-t_{j-1})) = m_{i}\left(\sum_{j=\alpha_{i-1}+1}^{\alpha_{i}}(t_{j}-t_{j-1})\right) = m_{i}(T_{i}-T_{i-1})$. Hence:

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{k}\left(\sum_{j=\alpha_{i-1}+1}^{\alpha_{i}}(m_{i}(t_{j}-t_{j-1}))\right) = \sum_{i=1}^{k}m_{i}(T_{i}-T_{i-1})
$$

Second: Since $\alpha_{0}<\alpha_{1}<...<\alpha_{k}$, follow that:

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{k}\left(\sum_{j=\alpha_{i-1}+1}^{\alpha_{i}}(m'_{j}(t_{j}-t_{j-1}))\right) = \sum^{\alpha_{k}}_{j=\alpha_{0}+1}(m'_{j}(t_{j}-t_{j-1}))
$$
remember that $\alpha_{0} = 0$ and $\alpha_{k} = n$, so: $\sum^{\alpha_{k}}_{j=\alpha_{0}+1}(m'_{j}(t_{j}-t_{j-1})) = \sum^{n}_{j=1}(m'_{j}(t_{j}-t_{j-1}))$
Hence:
$$
L(f,P)=\sum_{i=1}^{k}m_{i}(T_{i}-T_{i-1}) \leq \sum_{j=1}^{n}m'_{j}(t_{j}-t_{j-1})=L(f,Q)
$$
Similary for $U(f,P) \geq U(f,Q)$, just taking $m_{i} = max(f([T_{i-1},T_{i}]))$ and $m'_{j} = max(f([t_{j-1}, t_{j}]))$.

I have seen several proofs of this lemma in couple of books and none of them had to use the subsequence notation like those in your proof. I think it is not necessary to use such complicated notation which makes the proof harder to follow and risk making it even incorrect.

Start with the case $Q=P\cup {c},$ i.e. $Q$ contains one point more. The proof will require an easy analysis of one interval of $P$ which is split by $c$ into two intervals.
